# Invalid token when password resetting on Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity but ONLY on server side, not localhost

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, reset-password

I'm currently a beginner developer and I'm coding a password reset on my WebApp.

So as you can see everything is good in localhost but in live I got an invalid token and I don't know why:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> ForgotPassword(ForgotPasswordViewModel model)
{
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(model.Email);
                if (user == null)
                {
                    // Don't reveal that the user does not exist or is not confirmed
                    return RedirectToAction(nameof(ForgotPasswordConfirmation));
                }

                var code = await _userManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user);
                var callbackUrl = Url.ResetPasswordCallbackLink(user.Id, code, Request.Scheme);
                // Go to the change password page
                Response.Redirect(callbackUrl);
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return View(model);
}
```

I have checked the files in my FTP and everything is the same in AccountController.cs.
My token is supposed to be built with some special characters as "+" and I know my url will be like `http://localhost:5000/Account/ResetPassword?userId=00c2a3ad-64c8-49d3-95e5-49a120831b85&code=CfDJ8MVJi%2BoeOmp...`.
I have figured my callbackUrl has a different behavior online[at the %25](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xydbY.png)
Do I have decoded the URL and I found %25 means "%" in UTF-8 and I think it's an encoding/decoding problem so I trued to encode like this `code = HttpUtility.UrlEecode(code)` and decoding it but it's even worse because my token is getting invalid so maybe I got completely my theory is wrong.

Have you any clues? any soution to my problem? Glad to disscuss with.
Thanks for paying attention to my issue,

BR X-MAS Greetings,

Lap1

EDIT:

Okay first of all thanks for so I checked my versions on the both environnemnets by using dotnet -- info and here are my versions.[image: The server side] and [image: The localhost side]. So I know I installed a newer version of .NET Framework on my PC. But there is remaining the 2.0.0 version and it's used for every debugging. I don't know if the problem is here so If you have any clues I'm here to exploit this.

EDIT 2: so I uninstalled the newer versions (not a good idea buut I did just in case) to keep the same versions in 2.2.202 and my code still running

EDIT3: ok so I will keep updating my thoughts about my issue. I think it's because the code is encoded once before I see the URL. e.g. `+` becomes `%2F` and it becomes `%252F` in the URL. I never encoded the code string but  there is somewhere in the server some options...

Comment: There could be a few reasons for this issue. Here are a few things you could try to troubleshoot and fix the problem:
1) Check your live site's logs and error messages to see if there are any clues as to why the password reset feature is not working. 
2) Make sure that your live site and local development environment are using the same codebase. version of libraries.
3) Check your live site's database to make sure that it contains the same data as your local database
4) Check for any differences in the configuration of your live site and local environment. e.g. environment variables.

Comment: working well locally but failed in production, it's more likely that you missed some configuration...

Comment: Okay thanks for your comments, I will check it but if you have somme modus operandi to troubleshoot let me know I'm glad to hear it